# Multiplayer miles away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend and I really want to play minecraft together on the pc while we live in different towns half the time and barely get to see each other is there any way we could play multiplayer other than with a server?

Answer (score 4):

### Kind of

- [Minecraft Realms](https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/) is a paid service that you can connect with other users. It's like owning a server, but Mojang manages all the background processes and keeps it running. You may not be able to use plugins, but it will provide a platform that both of you can use.
- Some existing servers with large [plotworlds](https://minecraft-server-list.com/sort/Classic/) allow you free reign over terrain, and you don't have to do any work to keep them up. They still count as servers, but they may be open enough for you to consider.
- [LAN](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_LAN_world) connections will work in lieu of a server if you're close enough to share a wifi router.

### Why not use a server though?

Other people do the work of keeping them up, they're free, you and your friend can be far away from each other, and you can edit your builds while the other person is offline. They require minimum maintenance, but still connect you.

Comment: LAN can be extended over internet with programs like Hamachi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is a way to do this. However it is slightly complicated. Even though most people think that LAN worlds only work on the same internet connection, it is possible to get someone farther away to connect.

Step 1: Getting the port
When you first start the LAN world, it displays the port in the chat. Write down this number

Step 2: getting your ip:
Follow the instructions here:
http://lifehacker.com/5833108/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address
Scroll down to the local ip section for now. Your ip should look something like this: 192.168.1.# where # is any number, any size.

Step 3: Forwarding
In order to allow your friend to get on your world, you need to tell your internet router (the thing that gives all of your devices internet access) to listen for connections on that port. To do this, go to your router by connecting to 192.168.1.1 in your browser (those numbers is the ip of your router. Type it where you would type the address to a website). Then, navigate to port forwarding (on my router it is under firewall). You will need to add a new port to forward, and then select the ip of your computer that we found in step 2, and type in the port from step 1. You need to add this and save your changes (if necessary)

Step 4: Connecting
Now you need your friend to connect. You need to give him your external ip found in the link in step 2 (external, not internal. It should sook similar to your internal but with different numbers everywhere). You also need to give him the port. He should connect to you by entering this in direct connect from within minecraft: 100.20.30.400:12345 (where the "100.20.30.400" is YOUR external ip and "12334" is the port. You need to include the ":").

ISSUES:
The problem with this solution is you have to do this every single time you open the minecraft world. I would do some searching to find how to force minecraft to use a certain port every time for LAN, so you never have to change the forewarding. Also, your external ip changes sometimes (mine seems to change once every 1-2 months). This will require you to check your ip to make sure your friend is connecting to the correct one. Another issue is security. It isn't good to open too many port connections on your router. You should be deleting the ones you no longer use. (But don't delete anything that is already there)

EDIT: you may need to use Hamachi. See this link: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

I also agree with zyxrra. Servers are the real way to go. They can run on your own computer with minimal configuration. They do need to be port forwarded however, but the port always stays the same. (25565 I believe, but I could be wrong.) servers can stay online when you are not in the world, so your friend could work while you are not there. You would need to keep your computer on and awake for it to work though.

Comment: Could someone confirm my edit? Do you actually need hamachi or will the port forwarding solution work fine?

Comment: port forwarding will work, but so will Hamachi

Answer (score -1):

Use serverpro. They have free servers as long as you’re ok with waiting in a queue and getting a new ip every day (you have to complete a renew every hour or it’ll go down.) If you have a lot of friends on, I recommend premium. Its $60 a year and if you have friends always playing they can chip in. With premium theres no queue and no renew (so you can keep it up for weeks at a time). Its a secure way to play and really easy. It also supports plugins.